# How to combine two numeric lists in R both having same names ? And plot them in a Grouped Bar plot using R

Tags: r, plot

How to combine two numeric lists in R both having same names ? And plot them in a Grouped Bar plot using R
Here's my data :

```
> tally
2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 
4090 4360 4531 4616 4673 5445 5164 5463 5894 6215 6685 7007 7371 7696 8022 4887 

> tally1
2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 
4879 5061 5797 6119 6328 7151 6885 7251 7012 7527 7978 7819 8163 8515 8874 7528
```

I want to plot this in a grouped bargraph with y axis as values and x axis as years(2000 to 2015).Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier when the two vectors are bind into the same object, lets say a data frame.
The names of each variable `tally` and `tally1` can be found using

```
names(tally); names(tally1)
```

Let's use the names and the values to create a new data frame:

```
# original data    
tally <- c(4090, 4360, 4531, 4616, 4673, 5445, 5164, 5463, 5894, 6215, 6685, 7007, 7371, 7696, 8022, 4887 )
names(tally) <- 2000:2015

tally1 <- c(4879, 5061, 5797, 6119, 6328, 7151, 6885, 7251, 7012, 7527, 7978, 7819, 8163, 8515, 8874, 7528)
names(tally1) <- 2000:2015

# Insert into a data frame (in a tidy data format, which is the preferred way for packages like ggplot2. This means that every variable has its own column and every observation has its own row)
 tally.df <- data.frame(name = c(names(tally),names(tally1)),value = c(tally,tally1), tally = as.factor(c(rep(1,length(tally)),rep(2,length(tally1)))))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tally.df, aes(x = name, y = value, fill = tally)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

I've used a tidy data format, which is the preferred way for packages like ggplot2. This means that every variable has its own column and every observation has its own row. This is why there's a third element in the data frame which holds the tally index.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `base R`

```
barplot(rbind(tally, tally1), beside=TRUE, col = c('red', 'darkblue'))
legend("topleft", fill=c('red', 'darkblue'), legend = c('tally', 'tally1'))
```